# Why do we call predator birds "birds of prey"?

Tags: etymology

Pretty much what it says on the tin— usually if something is "X of Y", it is, usually because "X" is related to, or is of "Y" (e.g. "people of faith" means people who have faith)  In this case however, "bird of prey" doesn't mean that the bird is prey, but rather, that it eats prey, which is the opposite (it's the equivalent of construing "people of faith" to mean "atheist").  What is the reason we call birds that eat prey "of prey", instead of "predator birds"?

Comment: By the example you give, wouldn't "birds of prey" actually mean "birds who have prey"?  That seems pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: [Sense 3.a](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=prey) of _prey_: “The act or practice of preying”. They are birds of _preying_.

Comment: Because they prey on other birds or animals.

Comment: I can never remember if it is the Welsh or the Scots who *pray on Sundays, and their neighbours*.

Comment: 'of', like other prepositions, has many meanings. The bird of mine is a bird that I own. The bird of clay is a bird that is constructed from clay. The bird of Alcatraz comes from Alcatraz...etc. It just means a bird that has something to do with prey, and, in this case, kills it.

Comment: @rogermue I was unaware that birds were plants.

Comment: Note that English also has the expression "beasts of prey"—and that, as [this Ngram chart indicates](https://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=beast+of+prey%2Cbird+of+prey&year_start=1705&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeast%20of%20prey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbird%20of%20prey%3B%2Cc0), for most of the past 300 years—until about 1950—the two expressions were approximately equally frequent in written English (as represented by the Google Books database).

Answer (score 7):

From a grammatical point of view, "prey" preceeded by "of" is a genitive.

In many languages such as Latin, English or French, the genitive generally indicates the possession. But in this case, **the genitive denotes a description**, as for "*a man of  honour*" or "the day of reckoning".

*Bird of prey is a translation of the medieval latin "avis praedae". It may be a direct translation from latin or derived from its french equivalent "oiseau de proie".*

Comment: `In this case, the genitive denotes a description` – Isn't "man of honour" possessive (i.e. the man *has* honour)? Also, wouldn't `denotes a description` seem to suggest that a bird of prey can be *described* as prey (and by implication, that an eagle *is*, among other things, a prey)? That seems to contradict the intent of the term "bird of prey".

Comment: @GhotiandChips Following that train of thought produces “birds that have prey”, which kind of fits.

Comment: Constructions using "... de ..." (where de=of) are even more common in French than in English, as French tends not to use attributive nouns in the way English does, but uses a preposition instead. I wouldn't be surprised if there are several "... of ..." phrases that are direct translations of the French.

Answer (score 0):

Bird of prey is a sentence fragment, it has a direct readable meaning.

"birds of prey" : "of" is a preposition, so that means the subject is doing the object of the preposition, so "the bird is preying" is the meaning of birds of prey.